# Problem AngularJS checking if an object has a specific value

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to avoid duplicates and not be allowed to add empty items. If I send the same titolo (example, Harry Potter) again, I don't want it to be added to the $scope.libri for the second time. How can I check it before adding? This is my code now:

angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtr', function ($scope){

```
$scope.libri = [{id:'1',titolo:'Harry Potter',genere:'Fantasy',anno:'2001',autore:'J.K.Rowling'},
                {id:'2',titolo:'Il nome della rosa',genere:'Giallo',anno:'1994',autore:'Umberto Eco'},
                {id:'3',titolo:'Cado dalle nubi',genere:'Commedia',anno:'2014',autore:'Checco Zalone'}];
              
                


$scope.add = function () {
    
        $scope.libri.push({
            id: $scope.id,
            titolo: $scope.titolo,
            genere: $scope.genere,
            anno: $scope.anno,
            autore: $scope.autore
        });

        $scope.id = ' ';
        $scope.titolo = ' ';
        $scope.genere = ' ';
        $scope.anno = ' ';
        $scope.autore = ' ';
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$scope.libri.find(x => x.titolo === $scope.titolo)` in your add function before pushing to the array.

[`.find()` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Thanks. I tried with this code but it doesn't work it

Comment: This is the JS-standard way of finding an item in an array that matches a given criteria. If it's not working, then you're not doing it right.

Comment: Thank you Jacob. I'll try again it

Comment: Now it's ok the code! there was a problem with a ";"  thank you Jacob

Comment: @lello77 Glad to hear :)